# Value Error: could not convert string to float 'PLOT' after data.rdd.map

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, random-forest

I'm trying to build a random forest wit a csv file. My code so far:

```
CSV_PATH = "C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/tutorials/features_cut.csv"
APP_NAME = "Random Forest Example"
SPARK_URL = "local[*]"
RANDOM_SEED = 13579
TRAINING_DATA_RATIO = 0.7
RF_NUM_TREES = 3
RF_MAX_DEPTH = 4
RF_NUM_BINS = 32

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName(APP_NAME) \
.master(SPARK_URL) \
.getOrCreate()

data = spark.read \
.options(header = "true", inferschema = "true") \
.csv(CSV_PATH)

print("Total number of rows: %d" % df.count()) #470121
```

All the values in the DataFrame are Strings.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

transformed_data = data.rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[-1], Vectors.dense(x[0:-1])))
splits = [TRAINING_DATA_RATIO, 1.0 - TRAINING_DATA_RATIO]
training_data, test_data = transformed_data.randomSplit(splits, RANDOM_SEED)
```

Here the ERROR occures:

```
print("Number of training set rows: %s" % training_data.count())
print("Number of test set rows: %s " % test_data.count())

#Value Error: could not convert string to float 'PLOT'
```

I have trouble to understand how the rdd.map function works. 
I would appreciate your help.

UPDATEd:

```
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").setHandleInvalid("keep") for column in list(set(data.columns)) ]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
df_r = pipeline.fit(data).transform(data)
```

with the help of StringIndexer and Pipeline I could transform my strings into doubles.

Comment: Best guess is that one (or more) of the values in your data is a string that can not be converted to float and the DenseVector constructor is failing. Can you add the output of `df.printSchema()` to your question?

Comment: That was my guess too. I have for Example „Field_name = ‚SBRN‘, which cannot be converted, can it? What would I do in such an Situation? Does that mean  that I cannot usw. the DenseVector ? I can Show you more of my code tomorrow Morning. I don‘t have my laptop here at the Moment.

Comment: For categorical fields you would have to use VectorIndexer first. Why are you converting to `rdd` in the first place? Check out the `pyspark.ml` implementation of RandomForest and the example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier).

Comment: All right, I‘m gonna do that, First thing tomorrow. Thank you. Thank you! I keep you updated.

Comment: @pault I used the String Indexer, to convert my Strings into doubles. See above. Thank you for your help. Let's see, what comes next.